# Auth::attempt not working in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I want to check login with Laravel 5.2 Authentication.

In <5.2 I was worked this much easier and its now not working...
here is my code...

Iwas maked the tables without through migration...

The values are inserted like below...

Controller...

```
public function DoLogin(){

    $userdata = [
        'email' =>Input::get('email'),
        'pwd'   =>Input::get('pwd')
    ];

    if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){
        return "Success";
    }else{
        return "Error";
    }
} 



public function insert(){
    $data = [
        'email' =>'loremlipsum',
        'pwd'   =>Hash::make('12345'),
        'created_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];
    DB::table('users')->insert($data);
}
```

Every time its getting message as "**Error**".

```
1   id  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  Change Change   Drop Drop   

2   email   varchar(400)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   


3   pwd varchar(400)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   


4   created_at  timestamp       on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Change Change   Drop Drop   


5   updated_at  timestamp           No  0000-00-00 00:00:00     Change Change   Drop Drop
```

Form....

```
 <form action="{{URL::to(route('do_login'))}}" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="email"><br/><br/><br/>
        <input type="password" name="pwd"><br/><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
```

Remember 1 thing, I am using single table authentication like in 5.1 and below...

Thanks

Comment: Could you check if data inside `$userdata` is correct?

Comment: yes... here is the response.. array(2) { ["email"]=> string(11) "loremlipsum" ["pwd"]=> string(5) "12345" }

Comment: Maybe you'll need to rename `pwd` field to `password`.

Comment: paste your error or response here.